# how to parse data from custom message extension in android asmak

Tags: android, chat, asmack

```
<message id="64Vz5-10" to="210@localhost" type="chat"><body>idirkfkckckckcjdjdnx hdhdjcj</body><MediaType xmlns="jabber:client">1</MediaType><MediaPlaceHolder xmlns="jabber:client">AFGDSGYWY+VXXBNVNXVVX+J3VGSFSJFSSJSFJFS+FJS</MediaPlaceHolder><RemoteURL xmlns="jabber:client">http://www.google.com</RemoteURL></message>
```

**How to parse  values  from this given response in android ?**

I am trying to fetch values for MediaType, MediaPlaceHolder and RemoteURL.

This is what I am doing :

```
if (packet instanceof Message) {
    Message message = (Message) packet;
    if (message.getBody() != null) {
        Log.e(" message.toXML()", message.toXML() + '\n' + "  :  " + packet.toXML());

        //Get extension from message
        try {
            CustomExtension fileExt = (CustomExtension) message.getExtension(CustomExtension.NAMESPACE);
            // PacketExtension ext = message.getExtension(CustomExtension.ELEMENT_MEDIA_HOLDER);
            // Log.e("File Extension ", "description:----" + ext.toXML());
            if (fileExt != null) {
                //Get values from extension
                String filePath = fileExt.getFileType();
                System.out.println("Message --:" + message.getBody() + " File url:--" + filePath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
```

I am getting ClassCastException:

> org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension

Comment: add tag like that 
<message id="64Vz5-10" to="210@localhost" type="chat"><body>idirkfkckckckcjdjdnx hdhdjcj</body> <body xml:lang='MediaType'>1</body>  <body xml:lang='MediaPlaceHolder'>AFGDSGYWY+VXXBNVNXVVX+J3VGSFSJFSSJSFJFS+FJS</body><body xml:lang='RemoteURL'>http://www.google.com</body></message>    and get it  like  message.getBody("RemoteURL");

Comment: formatting for clarity